# JVM performance bottomed out overnight. What happened?

Tags: java, jvm

I'm not a Java developer but I find myself wearing that hat today, so bear with me.

When I stopped working on a file parser last night I was seeing benchmarks of 100k records per second-- which I was more than happy with. When I re-ran the same code against the same files this morning, I'm only seeing 10-12k records per second.

First thoughts might be that I changed something and introduced inefficient code but I've commented out larger swaths of the code than I had running last night and performance is still abysmal. At this point the program does virtually nothing except read files in the main loop and still reads them slowly.

I had a coworker run the fully-functional version of the jar on his own machine and he is seeing the 100k/s performance benchmarks I saw last night, so i can only assume something is wrong with my JVM/workstation.

Any ideas or thoughts on what I should be looking at? I hesitate to get into JVM performance tuning when I already know the stock JVM is more than capable of doing this task. I just don't understand what's changed since last night.

EDIT: I have rebooted the machine.

EDIT 2: It is now the next day. I booted up my laptop and ran the code, it's back to where it was in the first place-- 100k/ps. I checked out Windows' performance monitor yesterday and it didn't show an unusual amount of CPU, RAM or disk I/O so I'm really at a loss as to why this happened.

Perhaps I will look into JVM tuning after all if only to ensure I have a consistent experience.

Comment: Run a profiler (`jvisualvm` is included in the JDK).

Comment: Your machine may be busy with some background job, that is consuming you CPU or disk. If all else fails, the old "reboot" answer is usually a way to solve weirdness like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem seems to be resolved.

Since posting, one thing I've done is eliminate the Windows pagefile in case this was a matter of paging. It helped but not as much as I needed.

What seems to have made the biggest impact is dedicating a sizable amount of memory to the JVM upon launch. I'm guessing the JVM might have been struggling to allocate enough memory dynamically. I'm now running it with the following parameters:

```
-server -Xmx4096m -Xms4096m
```

I added the server flag since this is intended to be a long-running process and I don't care about start-up time, and the memory arguments should give the JVM a solid, static 4GB of memory to work with.

I've not had any performance issues since.

Comment: Keep in mind that the more memory you use, the more that will need to be garbage-collected later.